# phpmyadmin acess denied in my ubuntu labtop

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xampp, lampp

I have installed xampp but I did not access localhost/phpmyadmin/

I have done following changes

```
# since XAMPP 1.4.3
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    **Require all granted**
</Directory>
```

still I'm getting error

Error

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 2002 - No such file or directory The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured). Connection for
>   controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

`AllowOverride AuthConfig
 Require all granted`

or

`AllowOverride all
 Require all granted`

not thested yet but should be work

since @user3247809 do not mention the complete config, it could mistake in outconfig, so I make config the bypass the outhconfig.

Comment: Could you explain a bit why this answers the question?

Comment: Add that to your answer :)